# TouchID Forgets fingers after crash

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar, touch-id

Twice now I've been in a situation where I remove my two [USB-C Digital AC Multiport Adapters](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) while running in clamshell mode and found that nothing I could do would bring my my display. So, alas, hard reboot.

Each time this has happened though, my fingerprints appear to have been evicted from the machine.

Is it expected that TouchID forgets all registered fingers after a hard shutdown? Or is this some peculiar combination of the multiport adapters?

Comment: I have *exactly* the same problem when detaching my Macbook Pro 2017 from my external monitor, connected through a [Satechi USB-C Hub](https://satechi.net/collections/usb-type-c/products/satechi-slim-aluminum-type-c-multi-port-adapter). I find the actual blackscreen to be more annoying than the touchbar issue, but still.... ugh.

Comment: For me, I'm using the Apple multiport USB-C adapter (for reference). Hasn't happened in a while for me; though, I feel like I modified my habits to only ever pull one adapter at a time.